# MacBook Pro i7 won't automatically sleep

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, sleep, macbook-pro

I've been looking around quite a lot on various forums to work out why my computer wont automatically sleep after the set interval, however it does sleep properly when the lid is closed and the sleep command is executed from the menu. The screen also dims after the preset interval.

Unfortunately, I've tried a few things (which i'll list below) but non have been sucessful.

I've tried the following:

1. [Reset SMC controller](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964)
2. Deleted preference files for power management and systemUIServer
3. Looked at my logs to see what could be running, nothing obvious there either

According to one apple forum, it is a known issue that recent apple portables don't automatically sleep, but I find this quite hard to believe.

Does anybody have a similar issue, or know of any application/terminal commands that can be used to monitor processes to try to figure out whats stopping it from sleeping?

Comment: Neither of the 2 MacBook Pro i7's I have has ever had a problem with going to sleep, automatically or otherwise. Do you maybe have an application running that is preventing it?

Comment: Not that I know of. I quit all applications, and I even signed in using the built in Guest account. Still no luck.